# Code Contracts for mono?

Tags: .net, mono, code-contracts

Does mono support [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992)? I.e. if I build a class library, can mono users use my assembly?

If not, are there any alternative libraries? Preferably supporting static analysis (through a plugin or similar in visual studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [compatability website](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility), Monos Code Contracts API is done but the tooling is not yet complete.

**EDIT**: The newest version of Mono (2.8) only supports Contract.Requires calls and you have to rewrite you code with ccrewrite, [link](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/2.8.0/#codecontracts).

Comment: There was additional development in the Google SoC 2011 and 2012. The 2.11.4 preview release seems to incorporate this code: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Oct-02.html

Comment: That link drops me in an index page.