# Contract.Requires usage

Tags: c#, design-by-contract

Here is my problem. I am a very big fan of Design by contract, I am using this concept especially when developing libraries that can be used by other developers. I just found out a new way of doing this which is: `Contract.Requires` instead of `Exception`:
So instead of having:

```
public void SomeMethod(string name){
   if(name==null) throw new NullArgumentException("Null values not supported");
}
```

I now have:

```
public void SomeMethod(string name){
   Contract.Requires(name != null);
}
```

**EDIT**: I am working under VS2010 on debug mode.

Problem: `Contract.Requires` does not do anything, even when `name` is `null`!

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412847.aspx) documentation says:

> Specifies a precondition contract for the enclosing method or
>   property.

But nothing is specified in case the condition is not met!

I also noticed there are [other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.requires.aspx) `Contract.Requires` overloads that throw exception, display message... but then what is `Contract.Requires(Boolean)` for?

**EDIT** Answer below highlighted that a plug-in must be installed to have the full power of `Contract` API but then what about Mono users who want their code to behave the same on different platforms?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483055/code-contracts-for-mono

Comment: Thanks for the tip. With all this hassle I think I better have to stick to the old way of throwing exceptions

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should do the following:

1. Install the Code Contracts add-in as nfechner has noted
2. Go to the project properties, 'Code Contracts' folder
3. Check 'Perform Runtime Contract Checking'
4. Switch 'Assembly Mode' to 'Standard Contract Requires'
5. Substitute your `Contract.Requires` with `Contract.Requires<SomeException>` (the first one throws `System.Diagnostics.ContractException` while the second throws the exception you specified which is important for public methods)

That's the basic setup. For more accurate configuration, [refer to the manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf)

If you use Mono, probably, Contract class is empty. I haven't done this, but chapter seven from the Contracts manual seems to explain how to provide your own implementation.

Comment: +1 for these tips. I would rather stick to exceptions in this case. Is there a similar tool for MONO?

Comment: I am not only interested in using this in MONO but looking for portability from Windows to Linux and vice versa

Comment: I'm not sure how it works, but I do think you should try implementing custom contract runtime. It should not be very difficult. I expect the implementation to be easily portable. If you do this and if you have VS Professional+, then you'll get the benefits of **compile-time** contract checking, which are valuable. I would give it a try.

Comment: @GETah: The Code Contracts plug-in performs a post-compilation step that rewrites the IL in your assembly to in include the runtime checks. If your assembly is compatible with Mono, it will perform the `Contract.Requires(...)` checks on both Windows and Linux. The only issue is with compiling the code on Linux, where the IL rewriter is not available. If you do all your development on Windows then Code Contracts will not in any way affect cross-platform compatibility.

Answer (score 11):

From the [Contract class docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.aspx#Y24):

> Important
>
> You must install a Visual Studio add-in to enforce contracts. The [Code
>   Contracts Premium Edition](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152461) add-in lets you specify static and run-time
>   checking of code contracts on the project Properties page. If you do
>   not enable run-time checking, contracts such as the [Contract.Ensures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract.ensures.aspx)
>   method will not throw exceptions during run time if a contract is
>   violated. The Visual Studio add-in does not ship with Visual Studio
>   2010 or the Windows SDK.

Comment: +1 for the tip but this resolves the problem only on one end. Please see my updates on the question

Answer (score 2):

With a message like this it is usually helpful to specify exactly what you have done.

For example, you do not mention in the original message if you have installed the VS Addon, nor that you have enabled it under your project properties,  or that you are actually running in debug vs release mode, etc.

Re `Contract.Requires` vs `Contract.Requires<Exception>`

`Contract.Requires` is recommended.
According to the manual

> If your code must throw a particular exception on failure of a
>   particular precondition, you can use the generic overloaded form
>   below. (Please read Section 5.1 before committing to this form in your
>   code. You cannot use `Requires < Exn <Exn>>` without running the contract tools
>   on all builds. If you do, you will get a runtime failure everytime.)