# Why does the Code Contracts do not appear in the project properties in VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to use [Code Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts) in Visual Studio 2019.

As mentioned in [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300815/contract-requires-usage) I install the [Code Contracts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RiSEResearchinSoftwareEngineering.CodeContractsforNET) for .NET.

But I dont see the Code Contracts in my project properties.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I haven't heard anything about code contracts in many years -- if you're looking at the project properties for a SDK-style project, I strongly suspect that noone's bothered to implement the UI for code contracts

Comment: On the web page of that tool: *"Works with Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015"*. I don't see 2017 nor 2019 there.

Comment: Code Contracts are unfortunately no longer supported.